# Number of ways to choose $4$ items from $6$ the same items such that order doesn't matter using the number of ways when the order does matter

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 2 problems and I was able to solve each.

Problem 1

How many ways you can draw 4 items from a box containing $6$ indistinguishable items such that the order is important?

My answer is $6^4$.

Problem 2

How many ways you can draw $4$ items from a box containing $6$ indistinguishable items such that the order is NOT important?

My answer is $84$ using the stars and bars concept.

My question is how can I use the answer in Problem 1 to solve Problem 2 and not using the stars and bars concept or any formula?

Comment: If the $6$ items are indistinguishable, how are you getting $126$ ways to select?

Comment: First of all, $\binom{9}{3} = 84$.  That is the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 4$ in the nonnegative integers, which could be interpreted as the number of ways of selecting four objects from six types of objects or the number of ways of placing four indistinguishable objects in six distinct boxes.  Do you have one of those problems in mind?  Otherwise, why isn't the answer to your question just $\binom{6}{4}$?

Comment: That is not correct unless I do not understand your problem statement correctly. If you were putting $6$ indistinguishable balls in $4$ different bins, that would be correct calculation for number of ways you can put the balls in those bins. For example, the first has $6$ balls and others none, First and second have $2$ each and last two have $1$ each etc...

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who tried to understand and solve the question I posted. I am sorry if there are missed information or I was not able to convey the question properly. Please see the revised body of my question.

Comment: I have very much confusion. If my understanding is right, by "draw 4 items from 6 indistinguishable item" you are meaning that you draw 4 times from a box that contains 6 identical items and put them back after you draw them?

Comment: Yes @macton, that is what I mean.

Comment: Then the problem doesn't make any sense. If the box conains 6 $x$s, then the only result you will get after drawing 4 times and putting back is $\{x,x,x,x\}$, isn't it?

Comment: @macton.
Here is a similar problem. Let us say We want to draw $2$ pieces of fruit from a bowl that contains $2$ apples, $2$ pears, and $2$ oranges. In how many ways can we do this such that:

a. The fruits are indistinguishable but the order matters.
The answer will be $3^2 = 9$

b.The fruits are indistinguishable and the order does not matter.
The answer will be 9-3 = 6.

My question is how can I get the number similar to "3" in my given problem.

Comment: Ok my bad for not English good :(

Comment: No problem @macton. Thank you for the time you spent giving feedback and suggestions to improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Let us number the items from 1 to 6.

> How many ways you can draw 4 items from a box containing 6 *different but indistinguishable* items (and put it back after drawn) such that the order is important?

This answer is $6^4$ as you written.

> How many ways you can draw 4 items from a box containing 6 *different but indistinguishable* items (and put it back after drawn) such that the order is **not** important?

If you are trying to derive 2 from 1, you would need to basically cut out the dulplicates, so a case-by-case examine is required. For example, the 4 ways to draw in the first problem
$$
(1,2,2,2), (2,1,2,2), (2,2,1,2), (2,2,2,1)
$$
corresponds to only one way to draw $\{1,2,2,2\}$ in the second problem. And there are 24 ways to draw in the first problem that only correspond to only one ways to draw $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Till this point you can see how undesirable is to cut everying dulplicate from the $6^4$ down to 84.

And well, $6^4/84$ is not even an integer, you see.